# Can't set a global custom `cssFile` with --bundle .( does work without --bundle)

Tags: webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

We wanted to apply *different* GLOBAL CSS file according to some logic.

So we did a small test just to check if applying a custom name ( not `app.css` but `app1.css`) is working  :

We've used the sample project : `tns create aaa --ng` & webpack (all latest versions )

```
//main.ts:
platformNativeScriptDynamic({
                                startPageActionBarHidden: false ,
                                cssFile:"app1.css"
                            }) .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

It **DOES** work (without `--bundle`).

[image]

So you can see that Items are red :

[image]

**BUT** - Now we wanted to test with `--bundle` , [so we've modified the webpack json file also to search for `app1.css` and not `app.css`](https://gist.github.com/RoyiNamir/134ecdd9a28a01aa2bbfe2348c81a939#file-webpack-config-js-L163-L179)

(also modified `main.aot.ts`) with :

```
import { setCssFileName } from "application";
setCssFileName("./app1.css");
```

However - running `tns run android --bundle` does NOT work  :

[image]

`ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/load-application-css-angular.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/app' in 'C:\Users\sff\Desktop\delme1\ddd\node_modules\nativescript-dev-webpack'
 @ ../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/load-application-css-angular.js 5:49-65
 @ ./main.ts`

I've also tried with :

```
import { setCssFileName } from "application";
setCssFileName("./app1.css");
```

It run to completion but the `app1.css` file is not applied ( no reds here) :

[image]

We've tried many variations :

  `cssFile:"app1.css"
  cssFile:"./app1.css"
  cssFile:"~/app1.css"
  cssFile:"/app1.css"`

But when I think about it , this ^ is not related - becuase if I  do `cssFile:"app1.css"` **without** `--bundle` then  - `app1.css` is respected.
the problem is that it's not respected with `--bundle`

None of them worked.

**Question :**

It seems that `app1.css` with `--bundle` is not respected. Only `app.css` is respected.

How can I set a *global* custom css file for my app ?

---

[package.json](https://gist.github.com/411a3b7bae8d5f6a325b1797868ee379) 
project sample :  https://ufile.io/ge4to

nativescript@4.1.1
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

To change the application wide css File based on business logic you can use `application` module from nativescript core packages.

```
import { setCssFileName } from "application";
setCssFileName("./app1.css");
```

you can write the buisness logic inside the app.component.ts constructor and based on that calll `setCssFileName()` to change the app level css file.

here is playground demo for reference:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=LnjIr4

Comment: Thanks. However  - as I've said - it _doesn't_ work with `--bundle` .  And it _does_ work without `--bundle`

Comment: platformNativeScriptDynamic({
                                startPageActionBarHidden: false ,
                                cssFile:"app1.css"
                            }) .bootstrapModule(AppModule); this might not work with `--bundle` but this solution is working with `--bundle` also.

Comment: And to keep the modified webpack file as I have in my question ? ( I'm trying it - will update in 1 min )

Comment: there will no need to modify webpack file for changing global css.

Comment: OK let me try... updating in 1 min

Comment: [It doesn't work](https://i.imgur.com/k01XIPA.jpg) . App is running without applied CSS. Also i'm alomost positive that webpack.config should be changed in order to search for app1 and not app. [you can see here that css is not applied](https://i.imgur.com/G0juAZk.jpg). [Here is the project](https://ufile.io/whpfy) - if you want to try for yourself

Comment: we are not changing app.css to app1.css when it is bundling . we are changing it runtime so even if webpack.config search for app.css then it isn't issue.

Comment: are you sure there is nothing wrong with your css file?

Comment: also try running your project without changing css and using `--bundle`. it might be totally another issue.

Comment: Everything works if i set custom css without bundle so css is ok. Problem is only with bundle hence webpack. Run the proj and see

Comment: Mac or windows?

Comment: windows 8.1 pro

Comment: same project as I sent you ? how did you run it ? did you see red when tns run android --bundle ?

Comment: i had downloaded the project from playground link i had added and then run it locally using `--bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

Revert your webpack config file to the original configurations using app.scss and app.css

Add your main scss file app.scss

Add other files app1.android.scss, app2.android.scss, app3.android.scss ...

Modify your webpack config files to Copy this css files like other assets

On the plugins section:

```
 // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: "fonts/**" },
                { from: "**/*.jpg" },
                { from: "**/*.png" },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: "**/app1.android.css" },
                { from: "**/app2.android.css" },
                { from: "**/app3.android.css" },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

on your main.ts

```
const randomInt = 2;// your logic 
platformNativeScriptDynamic({
                                startPageActionBarHidden: false ,
                                cssFile:`app${randomInt}.android.css`
                            }) .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Do same thing on main.aot.ts, it will be used when enabling aot(--env.aot)

This should work, but it should be tuned to support iOS using variables and regex...

[image: demo]

Comment: Link - [I've tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately](https://i.imgur.com/hfUI3cA.jpg)
Is there any thing I've missed ?

Comment: _BTW I love your ns plugin and use it constantly._

Comment: I have some issue with my android configuration, I will check... Glad to hear you are using the plugin!

Comment: Thanks - that would be wonderful. ( [project demo sample](https://ufile.io/whpfy))

Comment: Btw imho AOT works only when --env.aot , which is not my case

Comment: Yes you're right, I thought aot compilation is default when using --bundle, but when passing --env.aot then main.aot.ts is used.

Comment: With your solution , it didn't apply the global css. ( look at the height of the items). https://i.imgur.com/XANjXkN.jpg.
Also - I don't understand why you "injected" `app1.android.css` and not `app1.css` - since "android" is removed in android systems. ( same in ios) [as you can see here](https://i.imgur.com/KMB3Fho.jpg)

Comment: Do you see the problem ?

Comment: For the css I just put the background color that's why the height is not applied. The problem that I see is when using webpack, css files are not included, I'm not a webpack expert, so I used a simple CopyPlugin for css like images(png...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173945/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-guissouma-issam).